# Matplotlib Default ColorMap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I'm extremely confused about what matplotlib's default colormap is.

[Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) indicates that Matplotlib defaults to rc values located in matplotlibrc on my local directory.

Looking in that file, I see that my image.cmap is defaulted to Jet, but when I run:

```
axes.pcolormesh(points[:, 0].reshape(shape), 
                points[:, 1].reshape(shape), 
                row['data'].reshape(shape))
```

I get yellows, reds, and blues (which are all part of 'jet'). But I also get whites, which I don't see in the colormap for Jet!

What do the whites represent then?[image]

Sorry the whites look more like... tan? here.

Data for this specific image:

```
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.333660345834009608e-01
1.143137439286294049e-01
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
1.143137439286294049e-01
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.333660345834009608e-01
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.524183252381725306e-01
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
5.715687196431470246e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
9.526145327385783512e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
7.620916261908626532e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.143137439286294049e-01
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
0.000000000000000000e+00
9.526145327385783512e-02
5.715687196431470246e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
3.810458130954313266e-02
1.905229065477156633e-02
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you have `np.nan` or `np.inf` in your data?

Comment: @tcaswell It's a density field, so unless I have 0 area I doubt I do. I will check though.

Comment: and do you have any funny clipping settings?  Colormaps have a mapping for 'bad' values (`inf`, `nan`), 'over' and 'under' values which can give you colors outside of the color map.

Comment: It seems that all my values are near or at 0. (all positive) There aren't any "weird" ones.

Comment: can you put up your data?  This is impossible to debug with out more information.